# A Symfony application should be bootable

Tags: symfony

I am auditing my Symfony Application on SensioLabs Insight and I am receiving the major issue "A Symfony application should be bootable", with a detailed issue "Unexpected end of script, die or exit probably encountered."

1) In the file config.yml, under doctrine:dbal:, the server_version is valued to 5.7, which is a suggestion in Stack Overflow of other Symfony developers who experienced the same issue, but not with the same detail "Unexpected end of script..."

2) I supposed that one of my files is not in the appropriate ASCII format => I launched the unix command "file $f" and verified that all of my files are with the attributes: PHP script, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

This did not solve my issue, and I do not know how to find--if this is what I have to do--the file(s) that cause(s) Symfony to generate this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked for support on sensiolabs insight website.
Here is the answer on 2018 August 6th :

> It seems the issue is linked to our latest build of PHP 7.1. We are going to work on it and I am going to keep you informed as soon as we have a fix.
>
> In the meantime, you can solve the problem by creating a `.sensiolabs.yml` file at the root of your project with the following content:
>
> `php_version: 7.1.2`
>
> This will use the previous PHP 7.1 version available on Insight, which does not have the problem. Have a look at https://insight.sensiolabs.com/docs/getting-started/configuring-sensiolabsinsight.html if you want to learn more about Insight configuration.

This worked for us.

Cheers,

Adrien

Comment: Thank you Adrien. This has avoided SensioLabs Insight to display the not justified error message "A Symfony application should be bootable"